# How to use onDraw() over xml layout? Invalidate not refreshing the onDraw() function

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

I've been trying to draw circles as player positions on a map, but I want to use XML for layout of other things around the layout such as buttons, having the map as a background.  However I can't seem to have both things working together.  They work perfectly fine separated and content is drawn fine if I use the custom view class as the setContentView.  But, if I use the customview in the xml, the onDraw() function only goes through once on start and cannot be invalidate()'d.

This is the layout XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TrackMap">
<com.b143lul.android.logreg.CircleView android:id="@+id/CircleView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/resized_track_2"
    ></com.b143lul.android.logreg.CircleView>
```

And my code in the custom view is:

```
public class CircleView extends View {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    JSONObject groupScores;
    Paint paint1;
    String localUsername = "";
    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public void init(Context context) {
        paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Bunch of circle drawing.
    }

    public void update(JSONObject allGroupScores, String username) {
        groupScores = allGroupScores;
        localUsername = username;
        invalidate();
        // Invalidate being used to refresh the draw function
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }
```

As for how I'm implementing the customview, I start in onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    circleView = new CircleView(this);
    //setContentView(circleView);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_map);
```

And then the update function of the customview class is called after the StringRequest that gets the scores every 5 seconds (which works all perfectly well):

```
try {
        groupScores = new JSONObject(response);
        circleView.update(groupScores, username);
```

So, I'm just wondering how I can use both at once, so that the drawing goes over the XML.  Sadly I can't seem to find anything on it online and I'm sorry if it's something really dumb I'm not doing!  Thanks in advance! :)

Just to mention: The update() function is being reached but `invalidate()` is not making the onDraw() refresh.  This is run if that view is used as setContentView() though.

Comment: Have you checked what size CircleView gets? I see you have wrap_content in layout xml, maybe it should be match_parent?

Comment: @TeemuLätti Thanks for the response!  Yes, the CircleView gets the right dimensions and it doesn't seem to affect the result.  The draw function is still not refreshing sadly. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out,

> circleView = new CircleView(this);

loads the class outside of the XML, which was part of the problem.  However, when I tried to load the view by findViewById() I got a NullPointerException.  So, the setContentView({Your layout XML}) needs to be called before trying to get the class by view.  AKA solution is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_map);
circleView = (CircleView)findViewById(R.id.CircleView);
```